# Sharing data between several instances

Tags: c#

I have a class `A` and a class `B` that both need to work with a class `C`.

I want class `A` and `B` to work on the same instance of `C` in a way that changes made in `A` to `C` will affect the `C` object used by `B`.

The only way I see to implement this is by using the observer pattern, but I am curious to know if there are any simple solution to this problem.

Comment: If you pass the same instance, you don't need to do anything, because it will be the same instance.

Comment: I tough values were not passed by reference, according to http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: class C is not value type

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp - I suspected that your "class C" means object which is actually `struct C`... If it is indeed true you'll have hard time making shared reference of it...

Comment: There could be more instance of C, but A changes should be reflected in B and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming declarations similar to following and setting `sharedC` in constructors:

```
class C{}
class A { private C sharedC; }
class B { private C sharedC; }
```

You'd use single instance of `C` and pass to instances of `A` and `B` that need shared copy.

```
var c = new C();

var a = new A(c);
var b = new B(c);
```

One of the simplest ways (assuming `C` is a `class`, not a `struct`)

Comment: Trying it ATM, I had the misconception that what you propose was impossible in C#.